# Html.BeginForm works but not Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax.beginform

I have an ASP MVC app that is attempting to submit my ViewModel which has a property called `Document` on it that is an `HttpPostedFileBase`.  The ViewModel binds fine when I use `@Html.BeginForm`, however if I change it to `@Ajax.BeginForm` and keep all things the same, it will bind the all the ViewModel properties EXCEPT for the `HttpPostedFileBase` property.  Any advice?

Relevant Code:

```
 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Add(ViewModel vm)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(200);
    }

 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Add", "Home", new AjaxOptions() {  HttpMethod = "Post" , AllowCache = false}, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Document.DocumentType);
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Document.DocumentTypeId);
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Document.File);

                <div class="container">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="lblAllReceivables" />                                </td>
                            <td >
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Document.File, new { type = "file", @class = "inputfile", @name = "file", @id = Model.Document.DocumentTypeId, @accept = ".pdf, .doc, docx" })
                                <label id="lblUpload" for="@Model.Document.DocumentTypeId"><i class="fa fa-upload" style="margin-right:10px;"></i>File</label>

                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2" >
                                Comments:<br />
                                <div class="input-group" style="width:100%;">
                                    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Document.Comments)

                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"><hr /></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr><td colspan="2" >  <input id="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-default btn-lg" type="submit" style="width:275px;" value="Submit  Application" /><a class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a></td></tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            }
```

Comment: Can you show the server side code?

Comment: You cannot use `Ajax.BeginForm()` to upload files. Use `$.ajax()` with `FormData` and set the correct ajax options - refer [How to append whole set of model to formdata and obtain it in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681) for an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that the browser does not support uploading a file via xmlhttprequest, which is what ajax.beginform uses to post data (as do all browser ajax libs). If you are using a html 5 browser, you can use the new file api to upload the file. for older browsers, you use an iframe to post the file. google for jquery plugin that wrap both those functions or just use the iframe appraoch (it pretty trival).

In specific cases I prefer to use another plugins like [DropzoneJS](http://sampathloku.blogspot.com/2014/02/dropzonejs-with-aspnet-mvc-5.html) it's better to handle it and you can upload multiple files easy.

Comment: This might be the issue, I think I'll have to go with @Html.BeginForm.  Thank you.